Как подружить 1С и Python
Можно ли как-то достучаться до базы данных 1С на MSSQL (в чистом виде - не экспортированной ни в excel, ни в сторонние СУБД) через Python (а именно SQLAlchemy) без использования обработчиков 1С, просто через параметры подключения или, возможно, через файл на локальном компьютере?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930062/python-call-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter

Можно, но
Лицензионное соглашение не позволяет использовать недокументированные фирмой "1С" средства для построения решений на платформе 1С:Предприятие. Это означает, что средства СУБД (или любые другие внесистемные средства) можно использовать только в том случае, если документация по продуктам линейки "1С:Предприятие" (включая ИТС) содержит явную рекомендацию использовать данное средство для решения данной задачи.
Во всех остальных случаях лицензионное соглашение позволяет использовать для построения решений только штатные средства платформы. В частности, можно обращаться к данным информационной базы только при помощи объектов "1С:Предприятия", специально предназначенных для работы с данными (запросы, справочники, документы и т.д.). Нельзя обращаться к данным информационной базы напрямую, минуя уровень объектов работы с данными "1С:Предприятия" - например при помощи средств СУБД или при помощи внешних компонент, которые реализуют прямой доступ к СУБД. Это ограничение распространяется на любые действия с данными, в том числе на изменение их структуры, а так же на чтение или изменение самих данных информационной базы или служебных данных "1С:Предприятия".
